# Klein's j-invariant and Ford circles

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-functions

Klein's j-invariant has structure which seems to resemble Ford circles:

[image: Klein's j-invariant]

The latter show up all over number theory (continued fractions, Rademacher's expansion for p(n), etc.)

Can someone explain the connection?

Comment: What is the diagram showing?

Comment: don't all modular forms have that symmetry?

Comment: Technically, modular forms transform with power-laws under the modular group, and only those of weight one are invariant. (With $\tau\mapsto\tau+1$ and $\tau\mapsto-\tau^{-1}$ as the generators of $\Gamma$, a modular form of weight $k$ transforms as $f(-1/\tau)=\tau^k f(\tau)$.) So modular forms of nonzero weight don't exactly have the same symmetry.

Comment: [^Error: meant to say weight zero in the first sentence.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ford circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle) are the [orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of a [horocycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horocycle) under the [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of the [modular group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) $\Gamma$ on the [upper half plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_half-plane) $\frak h$ (see e.g. [this entry](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/farey-fractions-ford-circles-and-sl_2/) of SBS).  [Modular forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form) of weight zero (of which the [$j$-invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) is an instance) are fully $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$-invariant. So the periods of $j$ (representing the [quotient](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/qtmanifold.pdf) $H/\Gamma$) [tile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) the hyperbolic plane (of which $\frak h$ is a [model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model)) according to the same [symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group) as the Ford circle tiling.

Answer (score 4):

The Ford circles are also a diagram of $PSL_2 \mathbb Z.$ A fairly good discussion is in The Sensual Quadratic Form by John H. Conway. The circles are horocycles instead of geodesics. Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane

Just to begin the part I really know, if you have a binary quadratic form $$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, $$ which we abbreviate as $\langle a,b,c \rangle, $ the traditional question is the possible primitively represented values of $f,$ that is $f(p,q)$ with $\gcd(p,q) = 1.$ However, this is really no different from finding the equivalence class of the form. Equivalence is probably best illustrated with the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives 
$$ H =\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  2a  &  b  \\
  b  &  2c  
\end{array} 
  \right).
$$

Take a matrix in $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ and multiply with that matrix on the right of H and its transpose on the left, as in
$$
 \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \alpha  &  \gamma  \\
  \beta  &  \delta  
\end{array} 
  \right)
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  2a  &  b  \\
  b  &  2c  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  \alpha  &  \beta  \\
  \gamma  &  \delta  
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; = \;
\left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  2A  &  B  \\
  B  &  2C  
\end{array} 
  \right).
$$
The result is the Hessian matrix of a new form $\langle A,B,C \rangle. $
The relationship to primitively represented values is that $f(\alpha, \gamma) = A.$